# ReflectionTypeLoadException from Roslyn-generated assembly

Tags: c#, roslyn, .net-4.7.2, visual-studio-2019

I've been fighting this for hours, and I can't find answers anywhere. I'm loading a file using Roslyn to compile some code into an assembly. I've explicitly loaded `MetadataReference`s, run `compilation.Emit`, and loaded the resulting memory stream into an assembly. But when I try to `GetTypes()` from the assembly, it can't find references I had explicitly loaded. Same with a single `GetType()`. The `LoaderExceptions` shows it's looking in all the wrong places.

```
private string CompileAndExecuteCodeTest(string inputFileName, string inputFileContent)
{
    var references = new List<MetadataReference> { [removed for brevity, multiple referenced] };

    var sourceLanguage = new CSharpLanguage(references);
    var syntaxTree = sourceLanguage.ParseText(inputFileContent, SourceCodeKind.Regular);
    var assemblyName = Path.GetRandomFileName() + ".generated.dll";

    var compilation = sourceLanguage
        .CreateLibraryCompilation(assemblyName: assemblyName, enableOptimisations: false)
        .AddReferences(references)
        .AddSyntaxTrees(syntaxTree);

    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    var emitResult = compilation.Emit(stream);

    if (emitResult.Success)
    {
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        var assembly = Assembly.Load(stream.GetBuffer());
        var types = assembly.GetTypes(); //// <<<<<< ERROR HERE

        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

LoaderException info:

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = MyTestProject, Version=0.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_0adcfb3eExp\devenv.exe.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/MyTestProject.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/MyTestProject/MyTestProject.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/MyTestProject.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/MyTestProject/MyTestProject.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/MyTestProject.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/MyTestProject/MyTestProject.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TestWindow/MyTestProject.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TestWindow/MyTestProject/MyTestProject.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/Debugger/MyTestProject.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/Debugger/MyTestProject/MyTestProject.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/MyTestProject.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/MyTestProject/MyTestProject.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/MyTestProject.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/MyTestProject/MyTestProject.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/MyTestProject.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/MyTestProject/MyTestProject.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/MyTestProject.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/MyTestProject/MyTestProject.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/MyTestProject.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/MyTestProject/MyTestProject.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TestWindow/MyTestProject.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TestWindow/MyTestProject/MyTestProject.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/Debugger/MyTestProject.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/Debugger/MyTestProject/MyTestProject.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/MyTestProject.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/MyTestProject/MyTestProject.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/MyTestProject.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/MyTestProject/MyTestProject.EXE.
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. You say that `assembly.GetTypes()` can't find the types you explicitly loaded, then say it throws an exception (so it can't be finding *any* types). By "explicitly loaded" do you mean the MetadataReferences you censored, or something else? Where does `MyTestProject` come from? Also, `GetBuffer()` will return a bunch of zeros at the end normally -- are you sure that `Assembly.Load` can handle those?

Comment: ```assembly.GetTypes()``` throws an exception, leading to the log shown above. By explicitly loaded, I mean into ```new List<MetadataReference>```. MyTestProject is one of the ```MetadataReference``` referenced assemblies. All the examples I've seen use ```Assembly.Load(stream.GetBuffer())```, and that executes without error.

Comment: The top-level exceptions (which I forgot), and since I can't seem to edit the question:

 ```System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: 'Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.'```

 ```"Could not load file or assembly 'MyTestProject, Version=0.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."```

Comment: OK, and where is `MyTestProject`? It probably can't locate it.

Comment: ```MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(MyTestProject).Assembly.Location)```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that assembly references don't contain any sort of path -- just the full name (including version, etc). The runtime then has to go searching in suitable places for the assembly. You can see it doing that in the bottom of your post. Of course, in your case, it doesn't know to look in the right place. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/how-the-runtime-locates-assemblies) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/specify-assembly-location)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using code from Ayende Rahien (http://ayende.com/blog/1376/solving-the-assembly-load-context-problem) and manually resolving the assemblies in `CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve`. I'm still not sure why they're not automatically resolving based on `MetadataReference.CreateFromFile`, but the code is working and compiling.

In case it goes away some day, here is the code:

```
public static class AssemblyLocator
{
    static Dictionary<string, Assembly>assemblies;

    public static void Init()
    {
        assemblies = new Dictionary<string, Assembly>();
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyLoad += new AssemblyLoadEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyLoad);
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);
    }

    static Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        Assembly assembly = null;
        assemblies.TryGetValue(args.Name, out assembly);
        return assembly;
    }

    static void CurrentDomain_AssemblyLoad(object sender, AssemblyLoadEventArgs args)
    {
        Assembly assembly = args.LoadedAssembly;
        assemblies[assembly.FullName] = assembly;
    }
}
```