# C# Assembly.GetType fails for AssemblyQualifiedName but works for FullName

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, gettype

Got a strange issue here. We're building a scripting system for our platform using Roslyn and reflection. In order to keep things as concise as possible, this works well for most types but fails for others (I have not been able to see a pattern here).

One of our requirements is that we reference any possible .net assembly so in order to create object instances we have to use the fully qualified assembly names. Normally I use the following helper method to first get the object Type:

This works well enough in most cases, however let's look at the following qualified type string: **"Serilog.LoggerConfiguration, Serilog, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=24c2f752a8e58a10"** (let's call this **typeString**).

```
public static Type GetType(string typeName)
{
    var type = Type.GetType(typeName);
    if (type != null) return type;
    foreach (var a in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
    {
        type = a.GetType(typeName);
        if (type != null)
            return type;
    }
    return null;
}
```

**AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()** contains the assembly mentioned above. Using the VS immediate window I can take that particular assembly and try the following (let's call the Serilog assembly **asm**):

1. asm.GetType(typeString) -> returns null. Strange since the assembly has the type in it. I checked by calling asm.GetTypes().
2. asm.GetType(typeString, false, false) -> returns null. Worth a shot.
3. asm.GetType("Serilog.LoggerConfiguration") -> returns the actual Type!

In short, I can find the type by using the FullName but not by using the AssemblyQualifiedName? This doesn't seem to make much sense. Armed with this information, I try some further tests (attempt to locate the Type in the Assembly using text matching):

asm.GetTypes().Where(x=>x.AssemblyQualifiedName == "Serilog.LoggerConfiguration, Serilog, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=24c2f752a8e58a10") -> this returns the correct Type.

My two questions regarding this are:

1. Why does my helper method fail to locate the type using the fully qualified name? By all accounts it should work.
2. Failing to find the type with my helper method, is it safe to add the above Linq search in case every other thing fails? I'm thinking reliability and performance, but any comments are welcome.

**EDIT 1**
In order to provide a working repro/example, I've done the following:

1. Create a new VS Solution, console app, .NET Framework 4.6.2
2. Add Nuget Package **Serilog, version 2.12.0**
3. Build the solution (so that the serilog.dll file will be placed within the bin folder)
4. Create a new folder within the bin folder, named "Lib" and move Serilog.dll there (to prevent it from being deleted on the next step)
5. Remove the Serilog nuget reference from the solution
6. Execute the following code under Main.cs:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   //this is the fully qualified assembly name
   string aqn = "Serilog.LoggerConfiguration, Serilog, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=24c2f752a8e58a10";

   //load assembly from file and insert it into the app domain
   Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom("Lib\\Serilog.dll");
   AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(asm.GetName());

   //this is null - fails only if the assembly is loaded using the Assembly.LoadFrom method.
   //Otherwise, if it's added to the solution as a nuget package it works.
   var direct = Type.GetType(aqn);

   //using Linq I can correctly find the Type.
   var linq = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Where(x => x.FullName.Contains("Serilog")).FirstOrDefault()
          .GetTypes().Where(y=>y.AssemblyQualifiedName == aqn).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. After some digging around it seems to be linked to the load context and needs a custom assembly resolver (more on this on [ReflectionTypeLoadException from Roslyn-generated assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61724231/reflectiontypeloadexception-from-roslyn-generated-assembly/61816983?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C23.8594#61816983))

In short, by implementing this custom assembly resolver, **Type.GetType(AssemblyQualifiedName)** works correctly, even for assemblies loaded using **Assembly.LoadFrom()**. This even works for nested types (defined using qualified assembly names).

**One note**: Be sure to call the Init() method only once, as otherwise you'll be reseting the assemblies dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

The remarks to [`Assembly.GetType(string name)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.gettype?view=net-7.0#system-reflection-assembly-gettype(system-string)) state the following:

> The `name` parameter **includes the namespace but not the assembly**. To search other assemblies for a type, use the `Type.GetType(String)` method overload, which can optionally include an assembly display name as part of the type name.

So try using `Type.GetType` with assembly qualified name:

```cs
var type = Type.GetType("Serilog.LoggerConfiguration, Serilog, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=24c2f752a8e58a10");
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2E7Ie3)

Comment: Hmm, good catch. However, that's the first thing I'm doing in the helper method - only if Type.GetType fails do I try to call Assembly.GetType... any ideas why Type.GetType might fail here?

Comment: @ChrisZO: If you want to focus on Type.GetType, I suggest you remove all mention of Assembly.GetType - it's clearly causing confusion. (And most of your question text is currently about Assembly.GetType.)

Comment: @ChrisZO - TBH I don't know. Can you please add a [mre] showing that failure?

Comment: @JonSkeet I would argue it even better be another separate question with a [mre].

Comment: @ JonSkeet - Sorry for the confusion. I tried to be as concise and clear as possible. Judging by Guru Stron's first reply, it seems I'm using Assembly.GetType incorrectly, so a more suitable title would be "C# Getting Type from AppDomain from AssemblyQualifiedName".

@GuruStron yes, of course. I'll try to create a new minimal solution to see if this is easily reproductible. Do you think it would be better to update the answer with the example or create a whole new question (possibly with the name I suggested above)?

Comment: @ChrisZO personally I would go with a new one, but it is totally up to you. In case of updating this one - be sure to update it, not remove the original one.

Comment: @GuruStron quite strange, while trying to create a bare sample, it seems to be an issue only when loading the assembly dynamically, using Assembly.LoadFrom. I'll get back on this after a bit of research.

Comment: @ChrisZO yes, I was not able to repro it either, that is why I asked for the repro.

Comment: @GuruStron I've edited the question and written down the steps I've taken to repro the issue (under "EDIT 1"). It seems to be related to using Assembly.LoadFrom.